# I want to integrate tomcat and apache using mod_jk for my grails application

Tags: apache, grails, tomcat7

I'd like to integrate tomcat and apache using `mod_jk` for my grails application. I want my static resources to be served from apache. The resources must be outside the application. I did the settings for apache like:

```
ProxyPass /appName ajp://localhost:8009/appName
ProxyPassReverse /appName ajp://localhost:8009/appName
```

Please let me know how to do this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProxyPass` is a directive used by `mod_proxy` not `mod_jk`.

If you want to use `mod_jk` use:

```
JkMount /appName/* workerApp
```

For this to work you need to configure the module `(/etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.load`):

```
LoadModule jk_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_jk.so

JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel debug
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
```

then add a worker (`/etc/apache2/workers.properties`):

```
workers.tomcat_home={PATH_TO_TOMCAT}
workers.java_home={PATH_TO_JVM}
ps=/
worker.list=workerApp
worker.workerApp.port=8009
worker.workerApp.host=localhost
worker.workerApp.type=ajp13
worker.workerApp.lbfactor=1
```

Be sure this line is not commented in Tomcat `server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="8009" address= "127.0.0.1" enableLookups= "false" redirectPort= "8443" protocol= "AJP/1.3" />
```

The Apache Tomcat Connector - [Reference Guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html) is a good source of information for `mod_jk` configuration.

Comment: I have some settings for mod_jk

LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile {path_to_file}

The specific file contain all necessaray settings for a worker.
But now i want my images,css from any external directory served througt apache so that all static content will be removed from tomcat.

Comment: I see, for that just use JkUnMount /resources/* workerApp (with the path of your static resources). You can also specify only a file type, by example by using JkUnMount /*.jpg workerApp Apache will serve all jpg images (and not Tomcat).

Comment: Have you tried to mount on root, like JkMount /* workerApp ? I have not managed to make it work in a week. ( Amazon EC2, Tomcat 6 )